# c# can i use discardable to avoid awaiting on an async function call?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a synchronous function `GetUserStatus()` which in turn calls an async function `LogAsync()`.

I do not want to await on `LogAsync()` but that doesn't seem to be something done as simple as it is to declare await. I was just hoping it's a matter of not awaiting, but no.

I know there are approaches like using `.ContinueWith()`, but in this particular case I want to know if just discarding the call to `LogAsync()` will let the current thread continue without waiting on `LogAsync()` to complete?

---

**Preferred pseudocode Setup**:

```
Public UserStatus GetUserStatus(){
    var status = GenerateStatus();
    _logger.LogAsync("Current Status: " + status.description()); //invoke and forget
    return status;
}
```

---

**Reality pseudocode**:

```
Public async UserStatus GetUserStatus(){
    var status = GenerateStatus();
    await _logger.LogAsync("Current Status: " + status.description()); //I don't want to wait for this
    return status;
}
```

---

**Will using discardable work like this?**:

```
Public UserStatus GetUserStatus(){
    var status = GenerateStatus();
    _ = _logger.LogAsync("Current Status: " + status.description()); //will this await?
    return status;
}
```

In this last case, will GetUserStatus() wait for LogAsync() or will it just continue right after the call?

Comment: `LogAsync` will yield when it reaches its first await, so caller will not continue "right after", but right after that first yield. If there's lots of code before the first async yield in `LogAsync`, it will be executed before control passes back to the caller.

Comment: @spender so how do i achieve true parallel execution between the caller thread and what ever thread `LogAsync` is dispatched onto.  I absolutely don't want `GetUserStatus()` to wait for `LogAsync()`. I basically want to do pseudocode: `new Thread().run(()=> LogAsycn())`

Comment: I see no drawbacks using just `Task.Run(() => _logger.LogAsync());`, creating new thread is considered to be expensive, and you are going to flood your app with threads if it's done frequently

Comment: What is wrong with just `_logger.LogAsync("Current Status: " + status.description());` ?

Comment: @GuruStron That gives you a compiler warning. Using a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) explicitly tells the compiler that you are intentionally discarding the result, which avoids the warning.

Comment: @GabrielLuci also suppressing warnings) I think creating `Task` here seems to be an overkill.

Comment: Also depended on underlying library which is used it is possible that it already buffers logs (or has capability for that)  so warring about awaiting logging can be an overkill also.

Comment: Unless logging is a distinct bottleneck in your code, you've measured and identified this has a big impact on performance, then this is just [premature optimisation](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/). Most logging engines will just deal with this for you. I'd just `await` it and move on with your life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is: yes, you can use a discarable to avoid waiting for `LogAsync` to complete. (You don't technically need to use the discard, but doing so avoids a compiler warning telling you that you're not awaiting it.)

However, you should understand what's actually happening before you do that.

What spender is saying in the comments is that all asynchronous methods start running synchronously, and will return at the first `await` that acts on an incomplete `Task`. In a method like `LogAsync`, that would be whenever it stores the log entry to whatever storage medium it's going to (file system or database, for example). Once that I/O request is *started*, then it returns and `GetUserStatus` can continue. Usually, that's fine. The code before the I/O request is usually very minimal.

If you really wanted to not wait for *any* of the code in `LogAsync`, then you could move it to a new thread:

```
_ = Task.Run(() => _logger.LogAsync("Current Status: " + status.description()));
```

However, that's not free (there is overhead to that). And if this is an ASP.NET application, that's not a great idea since ASP.NET has a limited number of threads so, depending on the load of your application, it may bring you dangerously close to hitting that max. In my opinion, it's not worth it. I don't think you'll be gaining anything.

**The dangers**

This whole idea is called "fire and forget". The "forget" is the danger that you need to weigh. Because you're forgetting it, you have no way to know if it completed successfully. It could be a database error for example, but also, in the case of ASP.NET, if the app pool is ever restarted, IIS will kill the process once it knows that all HTTP requests have finished processing. It has no idea if any background jobs are running (like a fire and forget task). So there is the possibility of it being killed.

The logging could fail and you'll never know. Sure, 99.9999% of the time it'll be fine. But only you can answer if you can tolerate *any* log messages being lost without you ever knowing.

If you want to mitigate that risk, there are other ways of handling it in ways that can be more described like "do this later" rather than "fire and forget". One library that helps with that is [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) (I've never used it, but I've seen it discussed).

Comment: @Irdis If you leave it off, the compiler will warn you that the call is not awaited. If you use the [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards), you are telling the compiler that you are doing that on purpose, so it doesn't warn you anymore.

Comment: It's worth noting that creating Tasks isn't free. It's pretty likely that the overhead of running `Task.Run` outstrips any overhead of just `await`ing the log in the first place. Also if this is a concurrent application (like a web app) your much more likely to suffer thread starvation if you start threading every log in the application. Optimsation should be measured.

Comment: @Liam cheers for the advice. The async log was a just a made up case. That's not my actual code.